# How do I sign out of the desktop version of GitHub?

Tags: windows, git, github

This seems like a very silly question but I can not find any way to log out of GitHub on the windows desktop application. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 25):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> to get to the options menu from which you can click sign out.

[image: Options Panel]

Comment: that's a `CTRL +` comma

Answer (score 17):

For Mac

Top Left corner of the screen, next to Mac symbol->Github->Preference->Accounts->signout

For Windows
 Inside github, Right side next to Sync->Settings symbol->options->log out

Comment: What about other OS? answer should be covered all aspects.

Comment: @manetsus, if you are using open source os it will be same like Mac.

Answer (score 4):

This is easy just follow it . Settings>Option> 
Log out

[image]

and again for Login just click +Add Account

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it says [here](https://windows.github.com/release-notes.html) it seems like since version 1.0.39 you could log in and out by pressing **Alt + L**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple and hidden:

1. Open GitHub desktop
2. Click the <kbd>File</kbd> on the top toolbar
3. You can click <kbd>Sign In</kbd> or <kbd>Sign Out</kbd> on the window

Answer (score 1):

With the latest desktop version,

<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Option</kbd> > <kbd>Sign Out</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

For **macOS** users that end up here, in top bar click the **Github Desktop drowpdown > Preferences > Accounts > Sign out**

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple:

1. Just open Your GitHub Desktop App
2. Click on <kbd>File</kbd>
3. Select on option (the option Modern-Dialog Box will open where you can see your account and the <kbd>Sign out</kbd> Button)
4. Click on the <kbd>Sign out</kbd> Button.

You have successfully logged out from your GitHub Desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

follow this
**File** -> **Options** -> **git** -> **Provide username and email** ->**Click on Save**                         After that a popup github desktop window will be opened for verification. Provide details and that's it. Done!

Answer (score 0):

As at Oct2023, none of the above methods seem to work on the windows-browser version of github.  Also I don’t think the Windows-Control-Panel/Credential-Manager etc method is applicable for browser-web-logins.  However just clearing your browser cache will sort-of have the same effect (although not technically logging-you out, you won't be able to access your github account until you log-in again).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35152676)