# Not able to logout from Github Desktop

Tags: github-for-windows, github-desktop

I have just downloaded the Github for Desktop (Windows 64) but for some reason i am not able to logout from it, this is the screen which i am seeing, i dont see any toolbar or anything, anyone knows whats happening?

[image]

**UPDATE:1**

1. [not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960247/how-do-i-sign-out-of-the-desktop-version-of-github) i have tried this link and it deosnt resolve my issue
2. Alt key doesnt bring up the menu bar

Comment: hit ALT to get a menu?

Comment: @TheChubbyPanda, ALT key doesnt bring up the menu bar

Comment: If you open a repository, does the menu appear?

Comment: yes, i can see projects,groups,activity,milestiones,snippets menu in the browser

Comment: This is a duplicate of the afore mentioned question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960247/how-do-i-sign-out-of-the-desktop-version-of-github

Comment: Solution is the same as duplicate. CTRL + comma

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I sign out of the desktop version of GitHub?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960247/how-do-i-sign-out-of-the-desktop-version-of-github)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>.

This opens the following window:

[image: Options Panel]

Where you can click sign out.

---

Once you have cloned your first repository (or made one etc.), you will be brought to a window like this:

[image: Repository Screen]

Here you can press `File > Options` to be brought to the same options panel.